# Git and DiffTool problems : What do LOCAL and REMOTE point to?

Tags: git, difftool

Ive been working on getting tortoisemerge working as the difftool option in Git with my .gitconfig file currently showing :

```
   [diff]
        tool = tortoise

    [difftool "tortoise"]
        cmd = tortoisemerge.exe -mine:$LOCAL -base:$REMOTE

    [difftool]
        prompt = false
```

According to [tortoise merge docs](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseMerge_en/tme-automation.html) the 'mine' command states which file will be shown on the right, in a two way diff.

My question is, what do the LOCAL and REMOTE variables as provided by GIT actually point to? The [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) is a little vague stating that

> LOCAL is set to the name of the temporary file containing the contents of the diff pre-image and REMOTE is set to the name of the temporary file containing the contents of the diff post-image.

The problem arises when I modify a file, and then enter 'git difftool' tortoisemerge is started with the working directory file on the LEFT and not the right as I assume.
I know I can merely switch  the 'mine' and 'local' commands but I was trying to figure out what the local/remote points to and the best way to resolve this issue

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that means that `$LOCAL` is always the `a/whatever` in the diff output, while `$REMOTE` is the `b/whatever`.  In other words, if you do:

```
 git difftool master experiment -- Makefile
```

`$LOCAL` will be a temporary file showing the the state of `Makefile` in the `master` branch, while `$REMOTE` will be a temporary file showing its state in the `experiment` branch.

If you just run:

```
git difftool
```

... that shows you the difference between the index and your working tree, so for each file with differences, `$LOCAL` will be a temporary file that's the same as the version of the file in the index, while the `$REMOTE` will be the version of the file in your working tree.

Answer (score 182):

there are **4 components** to this (note that before this step, you would have already done a local-checkin.)

- The local-checkin that your git tree has: **LOCAL**
- The head of the remote repository (that is going to be merged): **REMOTE**
- common ancestor to both LOCAL and REMOTE: **BASE**
- The file that will be written as a result: **MERGED**.

Comment: So if you're on master, and do `git merge branch`, LOCAL is the master copy, REMOTE is the branch copy (regardless of repository), right?

Answer (score 1):

I am using TortoiseSvn for merge and diff and is working as expected. While in diff, it shows my working copy on the right.
My .gitconfig with TortoiseSvn is as follows

```
[diff]
    tool = tortoise


[merge]
    tool = tortoise


[mergetool "tortoise"]
    cmd = TortoiseMerge.exe -base:\"$BASE\" -mine:\"$LOCAL\" -theirs:\"$REMOTE\" -merged:\"$MERGED\"
[difftool "tortoise"]
    cmd = tortoisemerge.exe -mine:\"$REMOTE\" -base:\"$LOCAL\"
```